# Finding online RPG players for a play-by-chat RPG Campaign?

Tags: online-roleplaying, play-by-chat, finding-other-players

I'm thinking of running a Pathfinder campaign for Skype (text only) and I don't have a group of players. How can I go about recruiting people for play-by-chat games instead of in-person? Are there any online sites in which you can look for people that are looking to play in an online play-by-chat RPG Campaign?

Comment: [Related] [Where can I find other RPG players?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232)

Answer (score 29):

Let's combine some of this into a compendium.

Play-by-chat has been at least 80% of my time spent as a GM. It is a fun way to play because it allows immersion and in-character roleplaying to have more depth by allowing players to write their words and actions, which most people are quite comfortable with. But like all other RPG sessions, you need players. So, where to go?

### Start with those closest to you.

I have to mention this. Personally, though I have had many excellent roleplaying games with relative strangers, my most consistently good experiences are with current friends and family. Many times I have been surprised to discover that people I know are actually interested in the roleplaying genre. A good number of my former "mere acquaintances" have become good friends this way. I encourage you to casually mention this interest with other people to see if they share it -- *you might be pleasantly surprised*!

### The Internet

Beyond that, we move into the great interwebs -- the realm of cats and anonymous personas. The best part about the internet is its size. Unless you're into Barbie Horse Adventures RPG, you are bound to find like-minded people out there somewhere. (Honestly, you would probably find some players for that, too.)

A great place to start is going to the source, if you decide to use a [VT platform](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/what-software-is-available-for-virtual-table-tops/3361#3361). When you make that decision, you should visit their respective ***forums***. All of them have a section for setting up gaming groups. Even if you stick to playing by pure text, your choice of ruleset can provide additional players from the game's official forums and fansites as well. As a *Pathfinder* DM, you can post to and search through [Paizo's Online Campaign registrar](http://paizo.com/campaigns/).

In addition, there are Epic-Level powers available to you in the form of social media. As [ladenedge's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign/21543#21543) already helpfully points out, [Reddit's LFG section](http://www.reddit.com/r/lfg) is a great example. In addition, you can search:

- Facebook groups
- General social sites like [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com) and [Craigslist](http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites)
- Gamer-specific social sites like [NearbyGamers](http://nearbygamers.com/)
- RPG fan sites or forums (such as [RPG Directory](http://rpg-directory.com/), [RPG.net](http://forum.rpg.net/), or [Giant in the Playground](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?51-Finding-Players-(Recruitment)))

Just be aware that when recruiting random people from the internet, you are still vulnerable to some of the side effects that come with PUGs in online games, such as random AFKs, bad attitudes, cheating, and conflict. This can happen with friends in face-to-face gaming, too, but at least you have a relationship basis with those friends already. Be prepared to deal with player problems which are made more complex by anonymity.

It is dangerous to go alone. [Here, take this.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-players)

Beyond that, have fun, and be a little patient and choosy with forming your group. With the vast population of the internet available to you, I think you can afford to do so.

Comment: This goes way beyond a mere compendium and includes valuable personal perspective too. I think that first sentence sells short what follows. :)

Comment: +1 for the infos here AND in addition to that also for the mentioning of the PUGS. That is really a severe problem with online gaming (had quite a few groups that disbanded thanks to 1-2 of them)

Answer (score 10):

In my experience, the best place to find an online group is [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/lfg).  They even have a handy filter at the top for finding *only* [online games](http://www.reddit.com/r/lfg/search?q=%22%5BOnline%5D%22&restrict_sr=on&sort=new).  Pathfinder and D&D 3+ are very popular there, and other games pop up less frequently (I found an amazing Changeling game via reddit, for example.)

As others have mentioned, forums are a good second option:

- Giant in the Playground: [Finding Players (Recruitment)](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=51)
- RPG.net: [Gaming Gatherings](http://forum.rpg.net/forumdisplay.php?21-Gaming-Gatherings)

Post a message in all three places.  If you actually want to run a game, I reckon you'll have no trouble at all finding players - willing GMs are a hot commodity!

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you try [roll20.net](https://app.roll20.net/home/) you do a play by play setting, or you can upgrade, as you can add on screen maps, voice, and even video chat.

This also has regular chat, and other functions in this chat that make gameplay go much more smoothly.

Roll20 has a looking for group system. Within 24 hours you will find at least 6-7 players for a campaign guaranteed, or if you don't want to GM, then look for a campaing that is looking for players. Roll20 is designed to connect new ppl to play these games

Comment: And just to be clear, Roll20 does have it's own Looking For Group system which you can use to find players.

Comment: Yes, I recently started looking at this as a method to get back into games with old friends that don't live near me again. A couple extra slots can be easy to fill like this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It appears to be suggesting a play environment, but not how to find players, making it wholly unrelated to the question.

Comment: @doppelgreener roll20 has a looking for group system. Within 24 hours you will find at least 6-7 players for a campaign guaranteed, or if you don't want to GM, then look for a campaing that is looking for players. Roll20 is designed to connect new ppl to play these games

Comment: That is worthwhile to mention in your answer. Right now it's just talking about what you can do with it as a tabletop system, and isn't mentioning that stuff. I'll put myself forward as your target audience: I didn't know roll20 had that stuff until just now in your comment; your answer didn't make me aware of those things.

Answer (score 5):

Forums tend to favor play-by-post games on that forum; you may have better luck with IRC channels. There are many out there, but the only one I'm personally familiar with is [#giantitp](http://www.gamesurge.net/chat/giantitp/). They're not very big on *Pathfinder*, though, they prefer 3.5 standard.

Answer (score 4):

It's not nearly as common as Play-by-post games, but I've certainly seen posts recruiting for play-by-chat games on the [Paizo forums](http://paizo.com/campaigns/).  It's especially a good fit since you're looking for Pathfinder players.

Answer (score 3):

Most RPG Forums have sections for finding people for play-by-post, skype or in person games. Some links that may help (these are sites I have used before, although not for online games):

[Giant in the Playground](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=51)
[Knights 'n' Knaves](http://www.knights-n-knaves.com/phpbb3/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=d7042a2d8c21e6febddf476ce6766f4e)
[Role-Player.net](http://role-player.net/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=77)

However, I would suggest looking for Pathfinder-specific forums or sites if you can (I can't personally recommend any). A little google-fu can go a long way.

Alternatively, there are mailing lists out there for people like you. Again, I've never used any personally, but they are a good way to reach a lot of people with similar interests/intentions.

Answer (score 3):

[RPG-Directory.com](http://rpg-directory.com/) is a really active forum community for play-by-post roleplayers, perhaps a good place to start chatting with people and finding someone to suit your game?