# best place to find RPGs on skype?

Tags: adnd-2e, online-roleplaying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sites for finding online RPG players for a play-by-chat RPG Campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/sites-for-finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign)

What's the best way to find an RPG on skype? I play AD&D 2e, Rifts, a few others, but I'm willing to pick up a new system if the GM is good.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Try looking at this related question, @Dakeyras answer might have what you're looking for: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18665/4089 .

Comment: I would go so far as to say its a possible duplicate, as this question is just a subset of that one

Comment: I think the question LitheOhm give is perfect. We don't have to ask a question specific for every chat system.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! I'm glad to see more people into AD&D 2e.