# Is there a good way to play online?

Tags: online-roleplaying

I was introduced to table top RPGs last year, but then I got to move. The place where I live now is a very "cold" neighborhood. Houses are big and the land around them even bigger, so each family is kind of an isolated unity. I'm looking for a way to continue playing, but so far I had no luck, so I decided to check if there are online communities for playing RPGs. Could any of you give me some pointers on how I can do this? I'm 14 years old, male, don't know much about RPGs yet, but I have a genius IQ (160) so I can probably learn any set of rules relatively fast.

Comment: lol, a downvote already? well thanks for the warm welcome, I love you too.

Comment: Hi Finn, and welcome to the site. Which RPGs were you playing before and interested in continuing?

Comment: Hello, thanks. Dungeons and Dragons, not sure if this is the answer you were looking for. I'm willing to learn, and buy rule books if required, but for the moment I know little about the stuff. I remember I was a Paladin if that helps.

Comment: I checked www.enworld.org , and I don't know if it just an impression (since I've never came accross this kind of website before) but it looks like it is focused on finding people near you,  which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you checked [our question on finding players for an online game](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign)? If there's something missing, you could ask a new question and indicate what was missing in the existing questions (since people might wonder "isn't that a dupe of...?"). You can also join us in [chat] to talk if you'd like.