# Finding players: Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay Fourth Edition (Cubicle 7)

Tags: finding-other-players, wfrp-4e

How are folks finding players these days? I'm looking for Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay 4th edition enthusiasts. (It was very recently released.) I'm also finding that remote play is more realistic than being able to sit down at a table with others.

Comment: Related non-system-specific questions: [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players). [Finding online RPG players for a play-by-chat RPG Campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign)

Comment: Thanks for the tags @V2Blast. I'm new here.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help].

Comment: What's Cubicle 7 in this context?

Comment: @vicky_molokh Cubicle 7 is the publisher for WFRP 4th edition.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  We generally close questions about finding players as duplicate of our master question on that topic, see if that (and its linked question about online play) help you.