# Trying to find a place to join a Blue Rose AGE RPG campaign!

Tags: blue-rose

I have been searching for a site that i can find a GM who is looking for players for a Blue Rose: The AGE RPG of Romantic Fantasy campaign, but no one is running anything on Roll 20 right now, and I've joined the Green Ronin discord and it doesn't seem like anyone is running any games there either. Does anyone know of a site that i could try that might have some people with games open?

Comment: Welcome to our stack Demon God Lyndon! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how operate and you can also visit the [help] for even more information.

Comment: Hi, I suggested looking here, when we spoke in discord, but I was hoping [Finding online RPG players for a play-by-chat RPG Campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign) would have been enough. Perhaps if you add that the system in question or the way you want to play is different to the suggested duplicate questions we can [edit] your post to get a unique answer?

Comment: Alternatively we can discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat)